# Accessing objects in an array

Tags: reactjs, tableau-api

Newbie here! This is actually an update to this issue; I'm attempting to access a specific element, hoping someone can help me. I'll include the code and what it logs to the console:

```
console.log(nextProps.filterSliderApplied);
```

[what is logged to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTGEm.png)

What I'm trying to reference, even with just a print to the console, are currentVal, min, or max (so 20, 2, or 177932, respectively) . I've tried using various Objects methods, but I can't seem to isolate the individual elements. Any direction would really be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: can you please provide a codesandbox for your question?

Comment: Alex - so sorry, how do I provide a codesandbox?

Comment: Go to https://codesandbox.io/,after signup create new react project, try to reproduce your issue with minimum code, past the link here.

Comment: Alex - Thank you! Sorry for the delay, I was having a REALLY hard time determining which parts of the code might be relevant (it's a pretty big/complex app, and I only started learning JavaScript/React/Redux in the last 4 months). I've updated with the link to the codesandbox, and also with some progress I was able to make. Not a lot, but a little. :)

Comment: Make sure your code works , I'm getting this error `Could not find module in path: './Filterbar'`,where is `Filterbar.js`?

Comment: Well Alex, you have to trust me to not be an idiot messing around with the code in the sandbox after I've posted a link to it...sorry! I changed it so that it at least loads the slider now.

Comment: its work now, and your problem is an error in console? am I right?

Comment: Honestly, my problem is that I have no idea how to connect the tableau slider filter data with the Slider (e.g. if the quanitative filter in tableau goes from 1 to 100, I can't figure out how to tell the Slider to get that filter data from the tableau sheet). A coworker has written the app to pull in the categorical filters, but I can't seem to replicate what he has done for the quanitative filters. Not sure if I'm making sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Tableau, I've made some change to `Slider.js` and now you can access to your state , hope be helpful https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-https-u3jyg

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out quite some time ago and forgot to post an answer; basically, i needed to reference the key:

```
<Slider
defaultValue={filterSliderApplied[key].currentVal}
min={filterSliderApplied[key].min}
max={filterSliderApplied[key].max}
/>
```

There's a lot of other code involved, but this allowed me to directly access each value I was trying to target.